# How to enable FSRM quota with PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2016

To disable FSRM quota with PowerShell is command below.

```
Set-FsrmQuota D:\test -Disabled
```

Please tell me how to enable with PowerShell.

Best regards,

Comment: From the MS Docs site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/fileserverresourcemanager/set-fsrmquota?view=win10-ps I copied this example `Set-FsrmQuota -Path "C:\Shares" -Description "limit usage to 1.5 GB" -Size 1.5GB`

Comment: What do you mean by how to enable in powershell? Are you asking how to open powershell and run the command ?

Comment: Sorry, as my English skill is poor, I was not able to share what I would like to say to you.
I would like to re-enable a quota which was disabled, but Set-FsrmQuota command cannot enable a quota.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you know how to open PowerShell. The command you gave is quite similar, but if you add "-Disabled" you basically just set a switch to tell the template to be disabled. You could use the switch in case you want to set a certain template, but do not want to have it enabled yet. Or just to disable it. To enable, first check the exact name of the template.

Run:

```
Get-FsrmQuotaTemplate
```

After that use the command Gert Jan gave you, with the exact name of the template you choose from the previous command, and run it:

```
Reset-FsrmQuota -Path "D:\Test" -Template "5 GB Limit"
```

> Please note that "5 GB Limit" is the exact template name found with
>   the first command.

Now the template is set for the folder you chose.

If you want to set on a series of Homefolders for instance, you could do something like.

```
$homefolders = Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\home"
foreach($folder in $homefolders){
    Reset-FsrmQuota -Path "D:\Test\$($folder.name)" -Template "5 GB Limit"
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But Size parameter requires type of UInt64, not String.

Comment: I've edited my answer, and tested it. This should work. I used Set but actually ment to use Reset-FSRMQuota. Hope this helps!

Comment: Have you tried using the Reset-FSRMQuota?  Let me know if it works :)